# Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy'

Tags: python

Just successfully build **blender** out and would like to have a try (without installation).

- On one side: **blender** seems to look for **bpy** all the time.

```
➜  bin ./blender
Color management: using fallback mode for management
Color management: Error could not find role data role.
BLT_lang_init: 'locale' data path for translations not found, continuing
Read prefs: ~/.config/blender/2.92/config/userpref.blend
Color management: scene view "Filmic" not found, setting default "Standard".
blf_load_font_default: 'fonts' data path not found for 'droidsans.ttf', will not be able to display text
blf_load_font_default: 'fonts' data path not found for 'bmonofont-i18n.ttf', will not be able to display text
blf_load_font_default: 'fonts' data path not found for 'bmonofont-i18n.ttf', will not be able to display text
bpy: couldn't find 'scripts/modules', blender probably wont start.
Freestyle: couldn't find 'scripts/freestyle/modules', Freestyle won't work properly.
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): source/blender/python/intern/bpy_rna.c:7283 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): source/blender/python/intern/bpy_rna.c:7283 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): source/blender/python/intern/bpy_rna.c:7283 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): source/blender/python/intern/bpy_rna.c:7283 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): source/blender/python/intern/bpy_rna.c:7283 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): source/blender/python/intern/bpy_rna.c:7283 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy_types'
ERROR (bpy.rna): source/blender/python/intern/bpy_rna.c:7283 pyrna_srna_ExternalType: failed to find 'bpy_types' module
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy'
Error: dropbox with unknown operator: WM_OT_drop_blend_file
Python: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'bpy'

location: <unknown location>:-1
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::logic_error'
  what():  basic_string::_M_construct null not valid
[1]    3540013 abort (core dumped)  ./blender
```

- On the other side: it seems **[bpy](https://github.com/TylerGubala/blenderpy)** need **blender** to be built and installed **FIRST**.

```
➜  blenderpy git:(master) ✗ python setup.py build
running build
running build_py
creating build
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8
creating build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/blenderpy
copying blenderpy/post_install.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/blenderpy
copying blenderpy/pre_uninstall.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/blenderpy
copying blenderpy/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-x86_64-3.8/blenderpy
running build_ext
Preparing the build environment for CMake extension: "bpy"
Searching for compatible Blender online (this will take a while)
^Cinterrupted
```

Can anybody help to explain the relationship between **blender** and **bpy**? And which should be installed first? Is it possible to run **blender** without **bpy** scripts? etc.

Thank you

Comment: Don't know whether [this](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/info_overview.html) helps?

Comment: When you run make install it copies script files to required location If you have `blender` binary, that's not  . building `bpy` as a python module,   It is not possible to run blender without `bpy`  When you build blender it builds the bpy module.  Regular UI blender it is internal to the program, as a module a stand alone shared library that can be imported into any python application of the same python x.y version